# Null profile image selectable from Facebook

Tags: bug, profile-picture

I have no profile image on Facebook, but Stack Overflow allows me to select it as a null image

[image: Selection]

And It gives an error everywhere.

[image: After selecting]

In console it also gives error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

Comment: The response from FB is `"Unsupported get request. Object with ID '271413073289488' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"` - So you need to make sure you have a picture and that it's publicly accessible or upload the picture yourself...

Comment: Yes I have no image but Stackoverflow is not able prevent from selecting null image

Comment: Right... but that's what FB is returning as what could be your image - the fact it doesn't work now doesn't mean it may not in the future. If it doesn't work - why not just upload your own or go back to your identicon? (Or make sure you have a publicly accessible FB image as said)

Comment: If Facebook return it as my image then Why Every Where I have seen different image. in mobile It seems in blue color. In edge in seems in cross sign. Here is chrome image. Mean its null.

Comment: well ideally it would have to be a default image.. But you chose not to show the gravatar...

Comment: Luckily, you still have your hat.